# Are there frameless sliding glass shower doors that don't require any channel attached to the curb?

Tags: bathroom, shower, remodeling, sliding-glass-door

Are there frameless sliding glass shower doors that don't require any channel attached to the curb for the sliding section? I see a lot of them for sale online, but the pictures make it look like they have metal channels attached to the curb. Can't tell. I don't want to put anything on the curb except the fixed door and maybe a small guide. This is a DYI project.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but if you have no channel what's your plan for waterproofing the shower?  The channel is what keeps the water that runs down the inside of the door from dripping all over the curb, and ultimately onto the floor outside the shower.  You will never get a door without a channel to be waterproof.

Comment: this is a 5’ long shower. i’m fine with a channel for the fixed panel, but i don’t need it for the other half since there is very little spray. my floor is waterproofed too, so a little water is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they make such doors.  (e.g. https://www.framelessshowerdoors.com/sliding-doors/)  But they are only useful if the doors are far enough away from the water spray so that very little water gets under them.

Comment: i can’t make out from their verbiage or the pictures, plus they haven’t answered my emails. going to try again!

Comment: I've purchased from that company before and was happy with the results.  I'm surprised they're ignoring your emails.  Maybe try again?  If not, there are other companies that offer similar products.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up choosing a dreamline sliding door that comes with a stainless halfround rod to help keep water from getting out between the sliding portion and the curb. I chose to leave it off and not have any "junk" on the sloped curb. I purposely installed the shower head so that it points away from the door. Sometimes a few drops get out, but that's fine. This is a great door and I'm really happy with having it nearly frameless (only one channel on the fixed side) and how easy it was to put up. I have to say, the instructions are difficult to follow.